# IIS App pool stop

Tags: c#, .net, iis, iis-7

Today I face weird issue on my server IIS app pool stop I have to restart it manually to start my website.

I have Rapid fail Protection : true (5 min - 5 times)

I have try to generate that scenario in local IIS manually trigger division by zero error but IIS is not crashing.

I have tried to check event log but its too long lot of entries are there.

How to check why particular app pool crash due to which reason/exception?

Comment: did you check the IIS/windows logs?

Comment: go to your windows diagnostic tools and check the windows event logs, you might find some useful logs there

Comment: Export event log to a text file so that you can do some digging. If you don't want to do any serious troubleshooting, open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com

Comment: Lex Li I have export the events to txt file but could not get more detail. Might be that issue has not log to event log.